# How to query a json column for empty objects?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, types, jsonb

Looking to find all rows where a certain json column contains an empty object, `{}`. This is possible with JSON arrays, or if I am looking for a specific key in the object. But I just want to know if the object is empty. Can't seem to find an operator that will do this.

```
 dev=# \d test
     Table "public.test"
  Column | Type | Modifiers
 --------+------+-----------
  foo    | json |

 dev=# select * from test;
    foo
 ---------
  {"a":1}
  {"b":1}
  {}
 (3 rows)

 dev=# select * from test where foo != '{}';
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json <> unknown
 LINE 1: select * from test where foo != '{}';
                                      ^
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 dev=# select * from test where foo != to_json('{}'::text);
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json <> json
 LINE 1: select * from test where foo != to_json('{}'::text);
                                      ^
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 dwv=# select * from test where foo != '{}'::json;
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json <> json
 LINE 1: select * from test where foo != '{}'::json;
                                      ^
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There is **no equality (or inequality) operator** for the data type **`json`** as a whole, because equality is hard to establish. Consider [**`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) in Postgres 9.4 or later, where this is possible. More details in this related answer on dba.SE (last chapter):

- [How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64765/3684)

`SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` fail for the same reason (no equality operator).

Casting both sides of the expression to `text` allows the operators `=` or `<>`, but that's not normally reliable as there are many possible text representations for the *same* JSON value. However, for **this particular case (empty object)** it works just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo::text <> '{}'::text;
```

In Postgres 9.4 or later, cast to `jsonb` instead. (**Or use `jsonb` to begin with.**)

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo::jsonb <> '{}'::jsonb;
```

Or, to cover absolutely every possibility:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE  CASE json_typeof(foo)
          WHEN 'object' THEN foo::text <> '{}'::text
          WHEN 'array'  THEN foo::text <> '[]'::text
          ELSE true  -- other types are never "empty"
          END;
```

[The manual for `json_typeof()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.24.1.1.1)

> Possible types are `object`, `array`, `string`, `number`, `boolean`, and `null`.

Comment: Probably obvious but this works for empty arrays as well just replace the {} with []

Comment: If you're looking for nested structures, the following might be something you  could use: `select * from test where foo->>'property' = '[]';` where the structure might be something like: `{ "property": [], "foo": "bar" }`

Comment: This is pretty terrible where there are lots of rows, and each `foo` is a large structure; each one is coerced to text!

Comment: When i'm using this i didn' want to add '{}'::text. Is it alright? (I didn't used the foo::text also)

Comment: How do you you use jsonb instead i.e. what is the query?

Comment: @MasterJoe: For `jsonb`: `... WHERE foo = '{}';`

Answer (score 20):

Empty JSON array `[]` could also be relevant.

Then this could work for both `[]` and `{}`:

```
select * from test where length(foo::text) > 2 ;
```

Comment: Does this work for JSONB columns also?

Comment: yes, but not sure if this is optimal for jsonb

Answer (score 7):

You have to be careful. Casting all your data as a different type so you can compare it will have performance issues on a large database.

If your data has a consistent key then you can look for the existence of the key. For example if plan data is {} or {id: '1'}

then you can look for items without 'id'

```
SELECT * FROM public."user"
where NOT(plan ? 'id')
```

Answer (score 6):

As of PostgreSQL 9.5 this type of query with JSON data is not possible. On the other hand, I agree it would be very useful and created a request for it:

https://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general/suggestions/12305481-check-if-json-is-empty

Feel free to vote it, and hopefully it will be implemented!

Answer (score 3):

In 9.3 it is possible to count the pairs in each object and filter the ones with none

```
create table test (foo json);
insert into test (foo) values
('{"a":1, "c":2}'), ('{"b":1}'), ('{}');

select *
from test
where (select count(*) from json_each(foo) s) = 0;
 foo 
-----
 {}
```

or test the existence, probably faster for big objects

```
select *
from test
where not exists (select 1 from json_each(foo) s);
```

Both techniques will work flawlessly regardless of formating

Comment: Why the `s` after the json_each call in these examples? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @Stratus3D It is the mandatory alias for a subquery, in this case a function.

Comment: this also works for arrays by replacing `json_each` with `json_array_elements`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Postgres `<@` (included in) operator, see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html):

```
select '{"a":2, "b":"hello"}'::jsonb <@ '{}'::jsonb;  -- false
select '{}'::jsonb <@ '{}'::jsonb;                    -- true

select '[{"a":1}, {"a":2}, {"a":3}]'::jsonb <@ '[]'::jsonb;  -- false
select '[]'::jsonb <@ '[]'::jsonb;                           -- true
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JSON Functions and Operators documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) you can use the double arrow function (`->>`) to get a json object or array field as text. Then do an equality check against a string.

So this worked for me:

```
SELECT jsonb_col from my_table
WHERE jsonb_col ->> 'key' = '{}';
```

Or if it's nested more than one level use the path function (`#>>`)

```
SELECT jsonb_col from my_table
WHERE jsonb_col #>> '{key, nestedKey}' = '{}';
```

Currently supported version as of this writing:

> Supported Versions: Current (13) / 12 / 11 / 10 / 9.6

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON Functions in PostgreSQL 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) features `jsonb_path_exists`.

To avoid serializing big jsonb objects, this correctly returns true if object is not empty:

```
select data from block where jsonb_path_exists(data, '$ ? (exists (@.*))');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE JSON_LENGTH(column_name) = 0
```