# How to compare if a record exist with json data type field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to check if a record already exist on database, but I have one json data type field and I need to compare it too.
When I try check using `exists?` I got the following error:

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "arrangements"
WHERE "arrangements"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "arrangements"."account_id" = 1
AND "arrangements"."receiver_id" = 19 AND "config"."hardware" = '---
category: mobile
serial: ''00000013''
vehicle: 
' AND "arrangements"."recorded" = 't' LIMIT 1

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "config"
LINE 1: ...id" = 1 AND "arrangements"."receiver_id" = 19 AND "config"."...
                                                         ^
```

Code that I using to check if a exists:

```
@arrangement = Arrangement.new({account_id: receiver.account.id, receiver_id: receiver.id, config: params[:config], recorded: true})

if Arrangement.exists?(account_id: @arrangement.account_id, receiver_id: @arrangement.receiver_id, config: @arrangement.config, recorded: @arrangement.recorded)
    puts 'true'
end
```

I already tried:

```
if Arrangement.exists?(@arrangement)
   puts 'true'
end
```

But always return false

Table:

```
create_table :arrangements do |t|
  t.references :account,    index:   true
  t.references :receiver,   index:   true
  t.json       :config,     null:    false
  t.boolean    :recorded,   default: false
  t.datetime   :deleted_at, index:   true
  t.integer    :created_by
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: I guess `AND "config"."hardware" ` should be `AND "arrangements"."config" `??

Comment: It's hard to compare a whole `json` values. The `json` data type is just a container and there is no equality operator for the whole value defined (no `=`). You will like `jsonb` in the upcoming Postgres 9.4, which has that. [More details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare jsons. Try to compare some jsons values

`where("arrangements.config->>'category' = ?", params[:config][:category])`

Look [in postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) for other JSON functions and operators

Answer (score 2):

This will convert both field(in case it is just `json`) and the parameter(which will be a json string) to `jsonb`, and then perform a comparison of everything it contains.

```
def existing_config?(config)
  Arrangement.where("config::jsonb = ?::jsonb", config.to_json).any?
end
```