# How to query by "full" JSON field?

Tags: json, postgresql, types

I updated a few fields like this:

```
UPDATE designs 
SET prices = '{ "at": 507, "ch": 751, "de": 447 }' 
WHERE prices IS NULL;
```

Now I want to find all those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM designs 
WHERE prices = '{ "at": 507, "ch": 751, "de": 447 }';
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
```

Variations like `WHERE prices LIKE '%"at": 507, "ch": 751, "de": 447%'` doesn't work neither.

The field `prices` is from type `json` and used PG version is `9.3`

Comment: Given the content of your JSON document, the `hstore` data type might be a better choice here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! Going to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the operator `=` is not defined for `JSON` fields. If you *really* want to do this, your only option is to cast as `TEXT`, but I'm sure you understand the potential problems with that approach, e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM designs WHERE prices::TEXT = '{ "x": 3 }';
```

<s>However, it just occurred to me that a safe approach to that would be:</s>

```
SELECT * FROM designs WHERE prices::TEXT = '{ "x": 3 }'::JSON::TEXT;
```

Nope, this doesn't work. Apparently, the `JSON` data type preserves the whitespace of the original `JSON`, so if the whitespace in the two strings is different, it won't work. (I regard this as a bug, but others might disagree.)

**My answer is correct for 9.3, which the questioner is using, but if you are using 9.4+, Erwin Brandstetter's answer is the better choice.**

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature of the `json` type (even if not particularly useful to most). The proper solution is `jsonb` in pg 9.4.

Comment: Hm. Can we cast to `JSONB` to get field ordering and then cast to text to make it comparable?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Yes, consider the second query in my answer (no need to actually involve `text`).

Answer (score 3):

There is [**`jsonb`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-json.html) in Postgres **9.4**, which has an equality operator. This data type effectively ignores insignificant white space (and some other insignificant details), so your query would work *as is*:

```
SELECT *
FROM   designs 
WHERE  prices = '{ "at": 507, "ch": 751, "de": 447 }';
```

The same is not possible with `json` that preserves insignificant white space, so "equality" between two `json` values is hard to establish. You *could* compare text representations, but that's *not reliable*:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

Using pg 9.4 once more, you could also make this work with a `json` column, by casting the value to `jsonb` on the fly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   designs 
WHERE  prices::jsonb = '{ "at": 507, "ch": 751, "de": 447 }'::jsonb;
```

Comment: This is great to know! I should probably convert my few `JSON` fields to `JSONB`. Were the questioner using 9.4, this would be the correct answer.