# DISTINCT ON in an aggregate function in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, distinct, aggregate-functions

For my problem, we have a schema whereby one photo has many tags and also many comments. So if I have a query where I want all the comments and tags, it will multiply the rows together. So if one photo has 2 tags and 13 comments, I get 26 rows for that one photo:

```
SELECT
        tag.name, 
        comment.comment_id
FROM
        photo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag ON photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
```

[image]

That's fine for most things, but it means that if I `GROUP BY` and then `json_agg(tag.*)`, I get 13 copies of the first tag, and 13 copies of the second tag.

```
SELECT json_agg(tag.name) as tags
FROM
        photo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag ON photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY photo.photo_id
```

[image]

Instead I want an array that is only 'suburban' and 'city', like this:

```
 [
      {"tag_id":1,"name":"suburban"}, 
      {"tag_id":2,"name":"city"}
 ]
```

I could `json_agg(DISTINCT tag.name)`, but this will only make an array of tag names, when I want the entire row as json. I would like to `json_agg(DISTINCT ON(tag.name) tag.*)`, but that's not valid SQL apparently.

**How then can I simulate `DISTINCT ON` inside an aggregate function in Postgres?**

Comment: `json_agg(DISTINCT tag.name)` should work for you, have you tried this?

Comment: Can you just remove the join to `Comments`? You aren't selecting on anything in that table. If you need to keep it because you have something from it in your `WHERE` clause, perhaps then add every `tag` field to your `GROUP BY` and don't use `DISTINCT`

Comment: @PinnyM No because then json_agg just makes an array of tag names. I want an array of objects representing the whole row (my second query is just an example, in reality I want to `json_agg(tag.*)`

Comment: @JNevill No I can't, because I also want to select `json_agg(comment.*) AS comments`.

Comment: According to the docs, [json_agg "aggregates values as a JSON array"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html).  If all you want is to turn the row into json, use the `row_to_json` function.

Comment: No, I want an array of rows. Which is what json_agg(comment.*) would do. I don't just want one json object.

Comment: Can you please post exactly what you'd like the expected output to look like?  Still not clear to me...

Comment: Updated the question to have an expected output

Comment: You have presented your question clearly, but important information is still missing to determine the best query. 1st, *always* your version of Postgres. 2nd, retrieve the whole table, a buch of photos of just a single photo per query? Also, I doubt you really want `json_agg(comment.*)` that would include `photo_id` redundantly. Typically you'd want a subset without the redundant column, no?

Comment: json_agg doesn't work with distinct. It says there is no equality operator in JSON

Answer (score 55):

The most simple thing I discovered is to use `DISTINCT` over `jsonb` (**not json!**). 
(`jsonb_build_object` creates jsonb objects)

```
SELECT 
   JSON_AGG(
       DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('tag_id', photo_tag.tag_id, 
                                  'name', tag.name)) AS tags
FROM photo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag ON photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY photo.photo_id
```

Comment: Nice. Though is there a downside to using `jsonb` over `json`?

Comment: @kyw Please, have a look at [this article](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/). There are pros and cons of `jsonb` over `json` at the very beginning. As for me, the pros are really good :)

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Any doc or links that explain behaviour on DISTINCT in JSONB objects?
DISTINCT seems to me calculating distinct on the entire JSONB object and not just any key in the JSONB object would like to know how it works though.

Comment: DISTINCT with jsonb_build_object() work like a champ. Loved it.

Comment: thanks mate, much easier than the answers above

Comment: be sure to use `jsonb_build_object` and not `json_build_object`

Comment: Smart and simple. Happy to find this answer after lots of trial and error to work around the problem.

Answer (score 32):

Whenever you have a central table and want to left-join it to many rows in table A and also left-join it to many rows in table B, you get these problems of duplicating rows. It can especially throw off aggregrate functions like `COUNT` and `SUM` if you're not careful! So I think you need to construct your tags-for-each-photo and comments-for-each-photo separately, and then join them together:

```
WITH tags AS (
  SELECT  photo.photo_id, json_agg(row_to_json(tag.*)) AS tags
  FROM    photo
  LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag on photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
  GROUP BY photo.photo_id
),
comments AS (
  SELECT  photo.photo_id, json_agg(row_to_json(comment.*)) AS comments
  FROM    photo
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
  GROUP BY photo.photo_id
)
SELECT  COALESCE(tags.photo_id, comments.photo_id) AS photo_id,
        tags.tags,
        comments.comments
FROM    tags
FULL OUTER JOIN comments
ON      tags.photo_id = comments.photo_id
```

**EDIT:** If you really want to join everything together without CTEs, this looks like it gives correct results:

```
SELECT  photo.photo_id,
        to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT tag.*)) AS tags,
        to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT comment.*)) AS comments
FROM    photo
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag on photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY photo.photo_id
```

Comment: Hello, @paul is there anyway to add DISTINCT in the following query:-  
`json_agg( json_build_object ( 'id', ca.id, 'name',ca.name, 'url',ca.url) ) as authors`

Comment: I think you can do it, but it's a little tricky. It seems worth making a separate question!

Answer (score 28):

The cheapest and simplest `DISTINCT` operation is ... not to multiply rows in a "proxy cross join" in the first place. Aggregate first, *then* join. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

#### Best for returning few selected rows

***Assuming*** you actually don't want to retrieve the whole table, but just one or few selected photos at a time, with aggregated details. Then **`LATERAL` subqueries** are fast and elegant:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   photo p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(c) AS comments
   FROM   comment c
   WHERE  photo_id = p.photo_id
   ) c1
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(t) AS tags
   FROM   photo_tag pt
   JOIN   tag       t USING (tag_id)
   WHERE  pt.photo_id = p.photo_id
   ) t
WHERE  p.photo_id = 2;  -- arbitrary selection
```

This returns **whole rows** from `comment` and `tag`, aggregated into JSON arrays separately. Rows are not multiplies like in your attempt, but they are only as "distinct" as they are in your base tables.

**To additionally fold duplicates in the base data, see below.**

Notes:

- `LATERAL` and `json_agg()` require Postgres **9.3** or later.
- `json_agg(c)` is short for `json_agg(c.*)`.
- We do not need to `LEFT JOIN` because an aggregate function like `json_agg()` always returns a row.

**Typically**, you'd only want a **subset** of columns - *at least* excluding the redundant `photo_id`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   photo p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('comment_id', comment_id
                                   , 'comment', comment)) AS comments
   FROM   comment
   WHERE  photo_id = p.photo_id
   ) c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(t) AS tags
   FROM   photo_tag pt
   JOIN   tag       t USING (tag_id)
   WHERE  pt.photo_id = p.photo_id
   ) t
WHERE  p.photo_id = 2;
```

[**`json_build_object()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) was introduced with Postgres **9.4**. Used to be cumbersome in older versions because a `ROW` constructor doesn't preserve column names. But there are generic workarounds:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

Also allows to choose JSON key names freely, you don't have to stick to column names.

#### Best for returning all or most rows

```sql
SELECT p.*
     , COALESCE(c1.comments, '[]') AS comments
     , COALESCE(t.tags, '[]') AS tags
FROM   photo p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT photo_id
        , json_agg(json_build_object('comment_id', comment_id
                                   , 'comment', comment)) AS comments
   FROM   comment c
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c1 USING (photo_id)
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT photo_id , json_agg(t) AS tags
   FROM   photo_tag pt
   JOIN   tag       t USING (tag_id)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t USING (photo_id);
```

Once we retrieve enough rows, this gets cheaper than `LATERAL` subqueries. Works for Postgres **9.3+**.

Note the `USING` clause in the join condition. This way we can conveniently use `SELECT *` in the outer query without getting duplicate columns for `photo_id`. I didn't use `SELECT *` here because your deleted answer indicates you want *empty JSON arrays* instead of *NULL* for no tags / no comments.

#### Also remove existing duplicates in base tables

You can't just `json_agg(DISTINCT json_build_object(...))` because there is no equality operator for the data type `json`. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

There are various better ways:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   photo p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(to_json(c1.comment)) AS comments1
        , json_agg(json_build_object('comment', c1.comment)) AS comments2
        , json_agg(to_json(c1)) AS comments3
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT c.comment  -- folding dupes here
      FROM   comment c
      WHERE  c.photo_id = p.photo_id
   -- ORDER  BY comment --  any particular order?
      ) c1
   ) c2
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(DISTINCT t) AS tags  -- demonstrating jsonb_agg
   FROM   photo_tag pt
   JOIN   tag       t USING (tag_id)
   WHERE  pt.photo_id = p.photo_id
   ) t
WHERE  p.photo_id = 2;
```

Demonstrating 4 different techniques in `comments1`, `comments2`, `comments3` (redundantly) and `tags`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=61d1eb0cff0388aeb88fc10eaff54a9c)*
<sub>Old: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ee02/3) backpatched to Postgres 9.3; [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1ee02/4) for Postgres 9.6</sub>

Comment: having json_build_object(distinct...)) would have been awesome.

Comment: Hello, @Erwin is there anyway to add DISTINCT in the following query:- json_agg( json_build_object ( 'id', ca.id, 'name',ca.name, 'url',ca.url) ) as authors

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan: I added a chapter addressing that. Ask a *question* with details if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Been working with SQL for over twenty years, but there's always something new to learn... :o

Answer (score 5):

As stated in comments, json_agg does not serialize a row as an object, but builds a JSON array of the *values that you pass it*.  You'll need `row_to_json` to turn your row into a JSON object, and then `json_agg` to perform the aggregation to an array:

```
SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT row_to_json(comment)) as tags
FROM
    photo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.photo_id = photo.photo_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_tag ON photo_tag.photo_id = photo.photo_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON photo_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY photo.photo_id
```

Comment: Actually json_agg does implicitly convert a row into JSON. Have a look at this example I just made http://pastebin.com/8jVSNstd.

But the problem with your query is that because there is no JSON comparison operator, it can't find distinct rows because they're all JSON.

Comment: If I copy your exact code and run it, I get `ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json`, which is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @Miguel Hmm, have you tried calling DISTINCT on the row, like this: json_agg(DISTINCT tag)? If that doesn't work, you'll likely need a subquery to accomplish this.

Comment: That doesn't work because the row is implicitly converted to json and you get the same error. If you know how to do this with a sub query I'd love to know because I can't think of anything.