# Join Postgresql tables on json array columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two tables in postgresql with json array columns`tableA.B` and `tableB.B`. How to join these tables on these json columns?
i.e.

```
select tableA.id, tablA.A, tableB.id,tableA.B, tableB.name
from tableA, tableB 
where tableA.B = tableB.B 

--tableA--
id | A     | B                 
1  | 36464 | ["874746", "474657"] 
2  | 36465 | ["874748"] 
3  | 36466 | ["874736", "474654"] 

--tableB--
id | name  | B                 
1  | john  | ["8740246", "2474657"] 
2  | mary  | ["874748","874736"] 
3  | clara | ["874736", "474654"]
```

Comment: This question is not clearly defined without your version of Postgres and proper table definitions showing data types and constraints. Most importantly: `json` or `jsonb`? Are empty arrays or NULL values allowed and considered equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, with the data type **`jsonb`** in **Postgres 9.4** or later, this becomes **dead simple**. Your query would just work (ugly naming convention, code and duplicate names in the output aside).

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_a(a_id int, a int, b jsonb);
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
  (1, 36464, '["874746", "474657"]')
, (2, 36465, '["874748"]')
, (3, 36466, '["874736", "474654"]');

CREATE TEMP TABLE table_b(b_id int, name text, b jsonb);
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
  (1, 'john' , '["8740246", "2474657"]')
, (2, 'mary' , '["874748","874736"]')
, (3, 'clara', '["874736", "474654"]');
```

Query:

```
SELECT a_id, a, b.*
FROM   table_a a
JOIN   table_b b USING (b);  -- match on the whole jsonb column
```

That you even ask indicates you are using the data type `json`, for which no equality operator exists:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

You just didn't mention the most important details.

The obvious solution is to switch to `jsonb`.

---

#### Answer to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032626/join-postgresql-tables-on-json-array-columns/38033971#comment63506621_38032710)

> is it possible to flatten out b into new rows rather than an array?

Use [`jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)` or `jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT a_id, a, b.b_id, b.name, b_array_element
FROM   table_a a
JOIN   table_b b USING (b)
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(b) b_array_element
```

This returns only rows matching on the whole array. About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If you want to match on array elements instead, unnest your arrays before you join.
The whole setup seems to be in dire need of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: What about **[PostgreSql : Json Array to Rows using Lateral Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709474/postgresql-json-array-to-rows-using-lateral-join)**?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tableA AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id,
          36464 AS A,
          '["874746", "474657"]'::jsonb AS B
   UNION SELECT 2 AS id,
                36465 AS A,
                '["874748"]'::jsonb AS B
   UNION SELECT 3 AS id,
                36466 AS A,
                '["874736", "474654"]'::jsonb AS B),
     tableB AS
  ( SELECT 1 AS id,
           'john' AS name,
           '["8740246", "2474657"]'::jsonb AS B
   UNION SELECT 2 AS id,
                'mary' AS name,
                '["874748", "874736"]'::jsonb AS B
   UNION SELECT 3 AS id,
                'clara' AS name,
                '["874736", "474654"]'::jsonb AS B)
SELECT *
FROM tableA
inner join tableB using(B);
```

Gives you

```
          b           | id |   a   | id | name  
----------------------+----+-------+----+-------
 ["874736", "474654"] |  3 | 36466 |  3 | clara
```

Isn't it what you expect?

Comment: Thank you @Guillaume Thomas is it possible to flatten out b into new rows rather than an array?