# How to use comparison where operator for JSON

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I get this error when querying with a json column:

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: json = text
```

The column is defined as JSON with SQLAlchemy:

```
json_data = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False)
```

How do you compare with Postgres?

Answer (score 3):

There is no equality (or inequality) operator for the data type `json`. If you need to test the value as a whole, you might cast to **`jsonb`**:

```
... WHERE json_data::jsonb = jsonb '{}';
```

Or cast to text for simple cases:

```
... WHERE json_data::text = '{}';
```

But there are many valid text representations for the same `json` value - which is the reason why Postgres does not implement equality / inequality operators for the type.

See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)