# Check for empty hash inside where clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get all books that have nil empty string or empty hash on a property

```
Book.where(references: [nil, "", {}])
```

This gives me an error.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>   LINE 1: ...on_id" = $1 AND ("books"."references" IN ('', '{}') ...
>                                                                ^
>   DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
>   CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:

references is a json field on a postgres database

Comment: What is the error? Put the trace please.

Comment: Can you add more code? What’s building this array?

Answer (score 2):

I have found here 
    [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects)

```rb
Book.where(references: [nil, ""]).where("references::text = '{}'::text")
```